# What is the difference here that prevents this from working?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm reading a list of customer names and using each to find an element.

Before reading the list, I make can confirm this works when I hard-code the name,

```
    datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'ACME Anvil Company')]")
```

But when I read in the customer list and use it like this, I get a NoSuchElement exception.  I know I'm getting the name into the customer variable because the print statement confirms it.

```
for customer in customerlist:
    print("START OF DATA FOR CUSTOMER: " +customer)
    datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+customer+"')]")
```

Do I have something wrong with the '" +customer+ "' part?  I've tried it a bunch of different ways.

Comment: How was `customerlist` created?  There might be trailing spaces or newlines in the text, for example - print the `repr()` of the variable to see exactly what's in it.

Comment: What does Your `customerlist` look like? Have You checked that it is really the same as Your hardcoded string? (I mean `==`-checked, just printing isn't enough)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the list elements e.g. *customer*, includes leading or trailing white spaces. So when you print through `print()` statement you are overseeing those.

But when you use the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as:

```
datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+customer+"')]")
```

Those whitespaces comes into play and no matches are found.

---

### Solution

You can use the following solution:

```
datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'"+customer+"')]")
```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
datarow = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'"+customer+"')]")))
```

Comment: @jasonharper    I made the customer list just by entering names in a text file..... type name, press enter, type name, press enter....   So it makes sense that there's a character there I don't see.